# Gas estimation failed on BSC Testnet

Tags: solidity, remix, bsc

I've got the following error when I'm trying to deploy my token on BSC Testnet.

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

Also this is what I see on the error log

[image]

There is the contract code - https://codeshare.io/5XRgxj

Comment: It is a bug in the contract constructor, or some other contract called from it. Please include a minimal reproducible case in the question.

Comment: Do you want to see the contract code?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5XRgxj

Comment: Did you try debugging which line causes the problem?